# SSL Traffic Using a WebProxy from a Docker Container

Tags: docker, ssl, proxy, containers, fiddler

I am trying to setup my container to send some of its outgoing traffic to Fiddler (for debugging my application).

I setup it up like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("OAuthClient").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x =>
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://host.docker.internal:8888"),
        UseProxy = true
    };
    return handler;
});
```

And this works fine when I run normal HTTP traffic from the container.  It also works fine when I run HTTPS traffic from my dev machine.  When when I try to run HTTPS traffic from a container, I get the following error:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

And the inner exception is:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I looked that up and from what I can see it is a "Self Signed Certificate" issue.  But I am not sure where it thinks it is is finding the self signed certificate.  Is it the container, the host or the url I am trying to call?

I feel that a container using a fiddler proxy is common enough that this should be a solved problem.

**How can I pass my container's HTTPS traffic to fiddler?**

Comment: Hi!
Could you solve your issue?

Comment: @Menyus - Sorry, it has been a year since I asked this question and I don't recall how I worked around this issue.

Comment: No problem actually we figured it out. Might as well post it here in work hours.

Comment: @Menyus if you can post your solution it would be most helpful?

Comment: I no longer remember exactly but in a dockercompose file we have this comment
```# Uncomment this if you would like to use Fiddler. For Fiddler you need to forward messages for the Fiddler proxy.
      # - http_proxy=http://{your_local_ip_address}:8888/
      # - https_proxy=http://{your_local_ip_address}:8888/```

Comment: Oh and you had to copy fiddler cert too to the docker image